# vuetify flexbox items wrapping not directly on top of each other

Tags: flexbox, row, vuetify.js, col

I would like to display a number of cards in a flexbox.

Unfortunately, the items do not wrap properly in some browser window sizes. Example:

[image]

My Code:

```
<v-row>
   <v-col v-for="n in 7">
      <v-card
         max-width="344"
         outlined
         min-width="350"
         height="120"
      >
         Card
      </v-card>
   </v-col>
</v-row>
```

I created a pen for this: https://codepen.io/Tenarius/pen/poywYYW

*The problem is particularly with a resolution of **1920x1040**.*

How do I set the items so that they wrap exactly on top of each other despite `min-width` and `max-width` in every resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `flex-grow: 1` from `.col`.

It's distributing free space between the items.

Being that the number of items in each row varies, the free space will vary, leading to an uneven distribution.